# jquery confused same class to option in select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i want to be disabled duplicate options in my dropdown but my jquery are confuse.

```js
var map = {};
$('select.ex option').addClass(function () {
    if (map[this.value]) {
      $(this).prop('disabled',true)
    }
    map[this.value] = true;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class='ex'>
    <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<select class='ex'>
    <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

I necessary to write same class name. it's possible to edit my code to disabled duplicate options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.each` loop to iterate through your select then loop through option inside selects and if the value already exist inside `{}` remove them else mark it as true.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
//loop through select
$('select.ex').each(function() {
  var map = {}; //define this
  //loop through options
  $(this).find("option").each(function() {
    if (map[this.value]) {
      $(this).prop('disabled', true)
    } else {
      map[this.value] = true;
    }
  })

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class='ex'>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<select class='ex'>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```